# issue with rotation and uilabels with size set using NSString's sizeWithFont

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uilabel, autoresize, autorotate

I have a few UILabels in my view with their height set using `sizeWithFont:`.

I set the autoreszingMask to flexible width and height, however on rotate the width changes (am assuming because self.view's width changes and its set with a width relative to self.view) but the height of it doesn't change to fit the content again. This results in a large white space at the top and bottom.

Just wondering how I would go about re-sizing the UILabel on rotation? Is there any automatic way of doing this, or is there a way of getting all UILabels and re-doing `sizeWithFont` when the device is rotated?

The UILabels are subviews of UIView heirarchies used as headers for sections in my UITableView.

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was having a flexible left and right margin on a slightly offset uilabel.

If the label isn't centered then you need to choose left or right and set the flexible margin for one of those.

Answer (score 1):

You should really send `sizeToFit` to any UIView, especially UILabel, instead of forcing some arbitrary size on them.

The best approach is usually to first set the maximum width and current height, then send `sizeToFit`, then adjust the width again if necessary. In case of multiline labels it looks like the most foolproof way to avoid layout bugs.

Comment: sizeToFit results in really irrational behavior... how are you meant to use it? Thanks

Comment: well... I don't really know. It seems to just choose a random width and height, sometimes cutting off text, and sometimes just being strangely high. Rotating the device only changes the width.